# llama.cpp Sorry, your GGJTv1 file of type MOSTLY_Q4_1_SOME_F16 is not eligible for conversion

Tags: machine-learning, llama

This is the repo I am using to convert with

https://github.com/ggerganov/llama.cpp

```
python3.10 ~/llama.cpp/convert-llama-ggml-to-gguf.py --input ~/llama.cpp/models/gpt4-x-alpaca-13b-native-4bit-128g/ggml-model-q4_1.bin --output ~/llama.cpp/models/gpt4-x-alpaca-13b-native-4bit-128g/ggml-model-q4_1.gguf
```

ValueError: Quantizations changed in GGJTv2. Can only convert unquantized GGML files older than GGJTv2. Sorry, your GGJTv1 file of type MOSTLY_Q4_1_SOME_F16 is not eligible for conversion.

As you can see, I am unable to convert the bin file to a gguf file.

I got this file from

https://huggingface.co/anon8231489123/gpt4-x-alpaca-13b-native-4bit-128g/tree/main/gpt4-x-alpaca-13b-ggml-q4_1-from-gptq-4bit-128g

It gives me

ggml-model-q4_1.bin

This issue stems from me simply trying to run the model straight from llama.cpp/main.py, this is what happens

```
./main -m ~/llama.cpp/models/gpt4-x-alpaca-13b-native-4bit-128g/ggml-model-q4_1.bin -t 4 -c 2048 -n 2048 --color -i --instruct
```

It fails with

> Log start main: build = 1407 (465219b) main: built with cc (Ubuntu
> 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0 for x86_64-linux-gnu main: seed = 1697867527 gguf_init_from_file: invalid magic characters tjgg. error
> loading model: llama_model_loader: failed to load model from
> models/gpt4-x-alpaca-13b-native-4bit-128g/ggml-model-q4_1.bin
> llama_load_model_from_file: failed to load model
> llama_init_from_gpt_params: error: failed to load model
> 'models/gpt4-x-alpaca-13b-native-4bit-128g/ggml-model-q4_1.bin' main:
> error: unable to load model

Any help would be appreciated.